# Поиск элемента в DOM по значению ссылки

Tags: javascript, dom

Доброго всем времени суток господа, второй раз за сегодня

```
// ищем элемент по id
document.getElementById('ididid').className += 'super_css_class';
```

Вопрос: а как найти не по id, а по значению ссылки и поменять ей класс? Даже не по класу, а именно по значению. Допустим есть 100 ссылок на сайте, у одной из них href='http://ya.ru'.

```
//пробовал так, но это не то
document.location.href('http://ya.ru').className += 'super_css_class';
```

Comment: вот прям здесь работает

    document.querySelectorAll('a[href="/users/11304/eicto"]')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll)

```
document.querySelectorAll('a[href="/users/11304/eicto"]')
```

в ie работает нормально начиная с ie9,  [но есть polyfill](https://gist.github.com/branneman/1200441) и не один, подберите подходящий вам.