# Document.querySelectorAll поиск ссылки - не срабатывает

Tags: jquery, javascript

Приветствую всех

Тут буквально вот вот тема была, про поиск DOM объектов. Хотел спросить кое, что. Вроде обсудили и работает, а у меня не работает. Понимание у меня не как у людей с третьим глазом. [(вот это обсуждали)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/234768/javascript-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-dom-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8)

Собственно, код написан, строго по описанию. 6я ссылка вроде должна исчезать, но она все же не исчезает. Прошу указать, где не прав, и поставить на путь истинный

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style>
    .none {display:none}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<a href="ya.ru">1</a>
<a href="ya.ru">2</a>
<a href="ya.ru">3</a>
<a href="ya.ru">4</a>
<a href="ya.ru">5</a>
<a href="ya1.ru">6</a>
<a href="ya.ru">7</a>


<script>
    function(){document.querySelectorAll('a[href="ya1.ru"]').className += 'none';}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`querySelectorAll` возвращает `NodeList` а не `Node`. Следовательно надо пройти по нодам

```
var nl=document.querySelectorAll('a[href="ya1.ru"]');
for(var i = 0; i < nl.length; i++){
   nl[i].className +='none';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.querySelectorAll('a[href="ya1.ru"]')[0].className = 'none';
```